# ML.NET: type inference for csv loading?

Tags: ml.net

The bare minimum requirement of an ML library is that it be capable of inferring the types of the extraordinarily large number of fields in real world ML applications (for example: 2,000).

Real World ML Applications live in a pipeline. Literally: a pipeline as in UNIX/Linux style fifoq's, named pipes connected by a pipe symbol.  Not an abstraction called "pipeline" inside a document written in a third party language and compiled. These pipelines are generically (as in general, not templated) typed, and all tools associated with UNIX/Linux pipelines infer types at runtime.

These tools allow for dynamic generation and expansion of csv fields and types to arbitrary widths beyond the capacity of a single file to encode by hand.

So, once again, the bare minimum requirement of an ML library is that it have the capacity to open an ML file without throwing a timeline of work in the ML Engineer's lap when he can roll out an entire system using GNU tools + Python in the same amount of time.

This means inferring the types of the extraordinarily large number of fields in a potentially dynamically generated and rapidly changing CSV file.  Ideally, the same binary console app can be used for the CSV data at various stages of an evolving or developing pipeline such that annotating the field types and recompiling is unnecessary.

I am reviewing the ML.NET data-IO system, in addition to F#'s CsvProvider, and the available CSV libraries for C#.  I am also reviewing the CLR/CLI interop, as I can construct a C++ CSV inference system, but the CLR/CLI VS templates appear to work only on Windows platforms.

It seems there is no capability to load a CSV with the basic types inferred (datetime, double, int, string). Is that an accurate assessment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [new Dataframe API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-dataframe/). It has a `LoadCsv` method on it that will infer column types and it is compatible with ML.NET's `IDataView`.

Comment: Glad it helped! I'm not entirely sure if datetime is supported there yet, but if it's not it should be coming.